# How to connect to local github server through api

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a local server in my office, where i have github installed and configured to use. Currently we use tortoise svn to connect to the local repositories and manage it.

Now I need to connect to the github repositories installed on my local server using Github APIs. I know how to connect to remote github repo's using github API.

Currenlty i tried a API request to fetch a cloud github repo using `GET` request to `https://api.github.com/orgs/:username/repos` to list my organization repo's and i get correct response from the server.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1296269,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",      
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
   },
   ...
]
```

Similarly i wanted to do with my local server github repos. The local server named as `masterhub` in my host file and i can clone the repo like `git clone ssh://username@masterhub/git/sample.git` and it is working.

What i want now is **what is the endpoint i should make an API call to make github APIs work on local?**

**Note:** I know the github APIs [available](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to play based on my need but all i need to know is what is the endpoint i should hit?

Comment: Check out the enterprise docs https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.18/v3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GitHub Enterprise Server API is under a slightly different endpoint than the cloud version.  If the hostname for your server is `github.example.com`, then the API is available under `https://github.example.com/api/v3` instead of `https://api.github.com`.

So for your example above, you'd need to use `https://github.example.com/api/v3/orgs/:username/repos`.

Note that whatever you have configured in your SSH config file doesn't matter here: you need to use a hostname, not an SSH alias.  If you're not sure what that hostname should be, then look in `~/.ssh/config` and find the hostname, then use that.